# Is faceVertexUVs supposed to wrap around?

Tags: three.js

I noticed that in a `Geometry` the `faceVertexUVs` doesn't need to be the same size as the `faces` array. It appears to wrap-around and re-use the UVs of a previous face. For my application that is great, since the UV coordinates are simply repeated (it's a strip of the same object).  But is this the intended behaviour? That is, if I do this will it break somewhere/sometime?

Comment: That does not sound good. Are you using `CanvasRenderer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Geometry.faceVertexUVs[ 0 ]` should have the same length as `Geometry.faces`.

If that is not the case, it will result in unexpected behavior.

three.js r.64

Comment: Okay, I will avoid relying on the undefined behaviour. Too bad the UVs don't use an indexing system like the vertices though.